# How to find specific text syntax format in a cell with an Excel function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a cell formula to find/identify/validate if an adjacent cell contains characters in the correct format.

If there is a character "|", then it must be preceded or followed by any amount of text and then another "|" before the text ends or there is a space, otherwise the cell is wrong.

Examples:

```
|Name| |Surname| |City| = ok
|Name| |Surname| = ok
|Name| |Surname| New York = ok
New York |Name| |Surname| = ok
|Name| |City |Surname| = wrong
N|ame |City| |Surname| = wrong
|Surname| |ZipCode| = ok
```

Any ideas?

Comment: All that data is in a single cell? Can you tell us what you've already tried to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of stating the problem is:

1. `||` (consecutive `|`) are not allowed, nor those enclosing only two of more spaces<sup>*</sup>.
2. If there exists a `| |` (one space in between) in the text to be validated, it must immediately be preceded by any amount of non-`|` text, with a `|` or another `| |` immediately prior to *that*, **and** it must immediately be followed by any amount of non-`|` text followed by a `|` or another `| |`.
3. If there are no `| |` then there must either be no `|` **or** exactly two `|`.

Condition 1. is, technically, explicitly ruled out in the question, (*"any amount of text"* can mean none or space-only is allowed) but it can be inferred from the examples that this is the intent of the OP.

With the conditions re-worded as above a formula-only solution becomes readily apparent as seen applied in the following worksheet:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

This is the formula entered into `B2:B11`:

```dart
=IF(CHOOSE(MIN(3,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))),TRUE,FALSE,AND(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"| |","")))/3*2=2,LEN(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)-FIND("|",A1)-1)))>0)),"ok","wrong")
```

---

**Explanation:**

The prettified version of the formula is as follows:

```dart
=
IF(
  CHOOSE(
    MIN(3,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))),
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    AND(
      LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"| |","")))/3*2=2,
      LEN(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)-FIND("|",A1)-1)))>0
    )
  ),
  "ok",
  "wrong"
)
```

The three conditions above can be refactored to the following:

[a] There must be precisely 2 more `|` than those accounted for by the `| |`s (the first and the last ones).

**and**

[b] If there exist any `|`, there must be at least two of them, and the first two of them must be separated by at least one non-space character.

The formula for [a] is:

```dart
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"| |","")))/3*2=2
```

The formula for the intra-`|` text validation part of [b] is:

```dart
LEN(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)-FIND("|",A1)-1)))>0
```

The other part of [b] (i.e., that there can't only be one `|`) is taken care of by the `CHOOSE()` function, which also takes care of the case when there are no `|` (required since this edge case causes errors in formula [b] and an incorrect result for formula [a]).

The first argument of the `CHOOSE()` function,

```dart
MIN(3,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","")))
```

maps the possible counts of `|`s to the indexes `1`, `2`, and `3` like so: `[0,1,2,3,4,…]` → `[1,2,3,3,3,…]`, and thus the function returns `TRUE` for a count of `0`, `FALSE` for a count of `1`, and the result of the `AND()` function for all other counts.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> The condition not allowing two or more intra-`|` spaces can be relaxed by the use of the `TRIM()` function.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each `|xyz|` is in an individual cell, this formula will do the job for the `|xyz|` in `A1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1,1)="|",IF(FIND("|",A1,2)=LEN(A1),"ok","not ok"),"not ok"),"not ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was a tough question!
But after 4 hours stumbling in the dark, I think I got the right RegEx pattern

I created a small VBA function to give you a new type of formula `=RegExTest()`.
The formula checks if a given pattern matches the cell to check and returns true or false.

First, I tried to search all valid cells. I failed, the pattern was way too long.
Then I got the idea: Why not searching the invalid character combinations?

```
(\w+\|\w+|(^|\s)\w+\||\|\w+($|\s)|\|\|)
```

[image]

#### The idea behind

The pattern has 4 conditions. If any of them matches an invalid partial string, the formula will return *true*.  Otherwise it returns *false* which means there are no errors in the checked cell

```
CONDITION#1    or    CONDITION#2   or   CONDITION#3    or    CONDITION#4 
\w+ \| \w+          (^|\s) \w+ \|       \| \w+ ($|\s)          \| \|
"abc|abc"         "^abc|" or " abc|"   "|abc " or "|abc$"       "||"
```

#### RegEx in detail

1. A pattern like (xxx|yyy|zzz) is a group with 3 conditions and  one condition must be true
2. The combination `\|` stands for the `|` character which must be escaped because `|` alone is a special character
3. `\w+` stands for all letters a-z or numbers 0-9 or underlines. Since the following user-defined function uses the `ignorecase = true` setting, you don't need to specify uppercase letters A-Z
4. `^` stands for the cell value beginning and `$` for the cell value ending
5. `\s` stands for a single space. I ignore the fact that it also stands for tab and line breaks

Source: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN

#### How to use RegEx in Excel

That is what most people don't know. You actually can use RegEx in any Office program.
Open the VBA editor with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, add a new **module** and paste the code

```
Function RegExTest(rngCell As Range, strPattern As String) As Boolean        
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")        
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern        
    RegExTest = objRegEx.Test(rngCell.Value)        
End Function
```

Now, a new type of formula is available: `=RegExTest( <cell_to_check> , <RegEx_pattern> )`
which will return *true* if the pattern matches anywhere onto the checked cell value

In case anyone needs it, here is an [example workbook](http://ge.tt/9BIYLIx/v/0)